# Vue test reporter shows expected thrown error

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, mocha.js

I am testing if a component throws an error, the test passes as intended, still the reporter outputs the thrown error.
Is there a way to prevent this? I don't want to see the expected errors in my test output.

The application was generated using Vue CLI and I run the tests using `npm run test:unit` which corresponds to `vue-cli-service test:unit`.

I tried running vue-cli-service manually and passing `-q` and different reporters as per [docs](http://zinserjan.github.io/mocha-webpack/docs/installation/cli-usage.html) linked by `vue-cli-service test:unit --help` and they don't seem to work at all (no quiet run, no different reporter).

I am using mocha/chai.

My component's script

```js
export default {
  props: {
    foo: Array,
  },
  mounted() {
    this.bar();
  },
  methods: {
    bar() {
      if(this.foo.length === 0) {
        throw new Error("Array is empty");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The test

```js
describe('Component'), () => {
  let localVue;
  beforeEach(() => {
    localVue = createLocalVue();
    localVue.use(Vuetify);
  });
  
  it('throws an error if array is empty', () => {
    const items = [];
    
    const params = {
      locaVue,
      propsData: { foo: items },
    };
    
    const msg = "Array is empty";
    
    // shows error in console both with this statement
    expect(shallowMount.bind(shallowMount, Component, params)).to.throw(msg);
    
    // and this statement
    expect(() => shallowMount(Component, params)).to.throw(msg);
  });
});
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this (e.g., `expect(() => throw new Error()).to.throw()` passes without actually emitting an error). Can you show your test code?

Comment: Added an example similar to my test code

Comment: Seems like a known issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/641. I tried the recommended workaround to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

I am the same way in that I don't like a bunch of noise in my test output. What I do is temporarily reassign `console.error` and then assign it back. Try:

```
// store a reference to the original function
const originalConsoleError = console.error;
// reassign to a no-op
console.error = () => {};
/** 
 * run tests
*/
// restore to aid in debugging further tests
console.error = originalConsoleError;
```

Comment: would you rather I hide the hack in a library? LOL